# What is the best possible way to view a closing tag?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a large block of code which is giving me a bit of bother regarding brackets...etc...
Is there a site where I can paste HTML code. and view where I am missing closing tags?

Comment: which editor are u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the W3C validator service:

http://validator.w3.org/